# How to use new method under main method and how to call values from previous methods in differenc classes in java

Tags: java

In this program i created two classes, first class containing overloading methods and second class is the main class.
1. In second class i want to create method to display values obtained from methods used in first class.
2. And also having one doubt in first class, i created 4 methods in that. If i give two values for method 2 and method 3 (hided) it show error and what is that error and how to overcome it. 
Totally two questions. Can anyone solve this. Thank You..!

```
class overr
{
int tot;
void test()//method 1
    {
    System.out.println("Nothing to display");
    }
void test(int en,int ta)//method 2
    {
    tot = en+ta;
    System.out.println("en & ta  :"+en+" & "+ta);
    }
/*void test(int ma,int hi)//method 3
    {
    tot = hi;
    System.out.println("ma & hi :"+ma+" & "+hi);
    }*/
void test(int hi)//method 3
    {
    tot = hi;
    System.out.println("hi :"+hi);
    }
void test(int ge,int ph,int ch)//method 4
    {
    tot = ge+ph+ch;
    System.out.println("ge, ph & ch :"+ge+" & "+ph+" & "+ch);
    }
}
class overloading
{
public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    int to,to1,to2,to3;
    overr ob = new overr();
    ob.test();//method 1
    ob.test(55,44);//method 2
    ob.test(66);//method 3
    /*ob.test(66,78);//method 3*/
    ob.test(59,88,70);//method 4
    int display()
    {
    to = ob.test(55,44)+ob.test(66)+ob.test(59,88,70);
    return to;
    }
    System.out.println(to); 
    }
}
```

output:

```
overloading.java:40: error: ';' expected
                int display()
                           ^
1 error
```

Comment: I give up. What *is* that error? You've seen it, we haven't. Post it. It should have been included in your question in the first place.

Comment: He's probably referring to the error you get when you declare two different methods with exactly the same parameters and exactly the same name.

Comment: @John I don't care to speculate. He should have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method names are not very helpful, but you might try changing class `overr` to return something from the `test` methods,

```
class overr {
  int tot;

  int test()// method 1
  {
    System.out.println("Nothing to display");
    return 0;
  }

  int test(int en, int ta)// method 2
  {
    tot = en + ta;
    System.out.println("en + ta  :" + tot);
    return tot;
  }

  int test(int hi)// method 3
  {
    tot = hi;
    System.out.println("hi :" + hi);
    return tot;
  }

  int test(int ge, int ph, int ch)// method 4
  {
    tot = ge + ph + ch;
    System.out.println("ge + ph + ch :" + ge + " + "
        + ph + " + " + ch);
    return tot;
  }
}
```

Then class `overloading` might look like

```
// You can't define your method in a method like you were (without a lambda or
// anonymous class anyway).
static int display(overr ob) {
  int to = ob.test(55, 44) + ob.test(66)
      + ob.test(59, 88, 70);
  return to;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
  overr ob = new overr();
  ob.test();// method 1
  ob.test(55, 44);// method 2
  ob.test(66);// method 3
  /* ob.test(66,78);//method 3 */
  ob.test(59, 88, 70);// method 4
  int to = display(ob);
  System.out.println(to);
}
```

Finally, Java naming convention would rename your classes to `Overr` and `Overloading`.

Answer (score 0):

If you give two methods the same name, they must accept different parameters. Otherwise, the compiler could never determine which method you intended to call. For example:

```
public static void foo(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

public static void foo(int i) {
    System.out.println(2 * i);
}

public static void main(string args[]) {
    foo(2); // We have a problem. Which foo do we call?
}
```

Second, if you want to access variables from another class, you can either make them public members of the class, or you can return the values from a static method.

```
public class Class1 {
    public int x;
}

public class Class2 {
    public static int foo(int i) {
        return 2 * i + 1;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(string args[]) {
        Class1 myClass = new Class1();
        myClass.x = 2;
        System.out.println(myClass.x); // This prints 2

        int num = 5;
        int result = Class2.foo(5);
        System.out.println(result); // This prints 10
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your method `display()` inside the `main()` method. Nested methods are not allowed in java. Move the `display()` method outside the `main()` method and then call it.

```
// Main method without display()
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    int to, to1, to2, to3;
    overr ob = new overr();
    ob.test();// method 1
    ob.test(55, 44);// method 2
    ob.test(66);// method 3
    /* ob.test(66,78);//method 3 */
    ob.test(59, 88, 70);// method 4
    to = display(ob); // Call display method
    System.out.println(to);
}

// display method
public static int display(overr ob) { // note the static, as you're calling it in main() which is static
    return ob.test(55,44)+ob.test(66)+ob.test(59,88,70);
}
```